# ng serve permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, permissions, angular-cli

When trying to `ng serve` a new angular project it return me an error

```sh
[error] Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1260:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1325:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1458:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:62:10)
```

npm version : `6.4.1`

angular cli version : `8.3.25`

Node version : `10.15.2`

## What I've tryed

1. Restart multiple times my computer
2. I've tryed to find if the port was already in use with `netstat -a -o -n` but no
3. Change port and hostname to be sur : `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4401`
4. Tryed : `npm cache clean --force --unsafe-perm`

I am starting a new project in angular 8. I've didn't touche my angular projects since last year and all my old projects don't starts anymore with `ng serve`. I've look on the net and this error appends a lot with docker. I've install last week Docker sandbox on my laptop and add some problems of compatibility with it. Could it be related ?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? What did you do to fix it? I am also having the same issue with Angular 12.

Comment: It has been solved now, just referred another article. I changed my port from 4200 to 4300 in npm start script - https://superuser.com/questions/1437780/how-to-fix-listen-eacces-permission-denied-on-any-port