# angular serve leads to EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4201

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Environment:

OS: Windows 10

IDE: IntelliJ 2020.2

npm: 6.14.6

node: 12.18.3

Angular: 8.3.28

Following output from the `npm run serve`-command

```
An unhandled exception occurred: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4201
See "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-KxIEvo\angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! dummy@0.0.0 serve: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.local.json --port 4201`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dummy@0.0.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T10_05_54_238Z-debug.log
```

Following output from the debug-log

```
12 verbose stack Error: dummy@0.0.0 serve: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.local.json --port 4201
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

Following output from the angular-errors.log

```
[error] Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4201
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1296:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:68:8)
```

Solutions tried:

- running `netstat` on CMD > port 4200 on home (127.0.0.1) is not in use according to output
- only used physical network interfaces and disbaled the others (like Hyper-V, VirtualBox-interfaces, etc.)
- restart of the whole system > worked, BUT not satisfying, if there is another answer that could help precisely what is blocking that would be interesting

Other seen SO-contributions

- [ng server - listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485038/ng-server-listen-eacces-permission-denied-127-0-0-14200)
- [ng serve permission denied 127.0.0.1:4200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913788/ng-serve-permission-denied-127-0-0-14200)

Comment: This is an OS permissions issue and unrelated to node.
Try to run the parent process (i.e. git bash, webstorm etc) as an administrator and attempt creating the server again

Comment: Usually I have admin permissions, still tried it with explicitly running it with admin permissions, but same result.